# Get text of a header and assign it to a variable Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

I have this bit of html on my page

```
<h4 class="text-right numberOfRecords">Total: {{vm.numberOfRecords}}</h4>
```

I am trying to assign it to a variable in one of my tests in order to use it without resolving a promise every time. Currently I assign it like this...

```
totalComplaints = element(by.css('.numberOfRecords')).getText().then(function(text) {
   return parseInt(text.split(':')[1].trim());
});
```

...but I have to resolve a promise every time I want to access the variable like so

```
totalComplaints.then(function(total) {
   console.log('totalComplaints = ', total);
});
```

How can I assign the variable to just use something like this instead?

```
console.log('totalComplaints = ', totalComplaints);
```

Comment: You can use `async/await`. More detail look at http://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await .   Using `async/await` requires all your script change to async/await style.

Comment: I don't quite understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can stort the value in browser params:

```
element(by.css('.numberOfRecords')).getText().then(function(text) {
   browser.params.totalComplaints = parseInt(text.split(':')[1].trim());
});
```

And then call the value which is a string:

```
browser.params.totalComplaints
```

You can consider to change parseInt to regex:

```
text.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Protractor conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
    specs: ['spec.js']
};
```

**Jasmine spec.js**

```
describe('', ()=>{

    let totalComplaints;

    it('case 1', async ()=>{
        totalComplaints = await element(by.css('.numberOfRecords')).getText();

        totalComplaints = totalComplaints.split(':')[1].trim();

        console.log('in case 1:  totalComplaints = ', totalComplaints);
    });


    it('case 2', async ()=>{

        console.log('in case 2: totalComplaints = ', totalComplaints);
    });
});
```